# Usage of subprocess class in Python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

```
final="cacls " + "E:/" + "\"" + list1[2] + " " + list1[3] + "\""  + "  /p " + str
pro = subprocess.Popen(final,shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pro.communicate(bytes("Y\r\n",'utf-8'))
```

Trying to set permission to a folder Using Python but while running this command , User input needs to be provided too i.e

it asks ARE YOU SURE(Y/N) and the user needs to enter "Y" or "N"

The above code is not setting the permission.

This was the question i had asked before:

[Python code to send command through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028236/python-code-to-send-command-through-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

As a smart programmer, use [PBS](https://github.com/amoffat/pbs)

Then, the code is:

```
from pbs import type as echo# Isn't it echo for Windows? If not, use the correct one

script = Command("/path/to/cacls ")
print script(echo("Y"), ("E:/" + "\"" + list1[2] + " " + list1[3] + "\""  + "  /p " + str).split())
```